# Why does this happens to my mesh/textures

Tags: texturing

[image]
[image]
I used substance painter to paint the textures, and is worse when the mesh has subdivision surface (this is just with smooth shading) The metal and the yellow texture mix together

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is? that is just a loop cut, its perfectly normal to be there and shouldn't be much of a problem unless you did not UV unwrap your object correctly. What exactly are you trying to do? should the pole be completely yellow ?

Comment: the yellow part and the metallic part mix together in the loop cut

Comment: I am not sure but it looks like it was unwrapped before adding in that edge loop, So you would need to unwrap again so it takes into account that new edge loop. If you want to upload your blend I can take a look http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/